# Panel joining boards

Tags: panel, square

I am working with some local wood in Malaysia ([Nyatoh](https://www.wood-database.com/nyatoh/)) to make a small table top. Each 4” piece is slightly out of square.

Is it possible to join the 4 boards together bending them so that they are aligned and then square the entire table top, or should I square each piece before joining?

I was planning to clamp the wood with 4 way pressure when joining.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. The answer here is likely to be a firm no on working with the wood as-is, but we need a little more detail. How exactly are they out of square? Take a photo or two, do a little sketch if it might help, but at least draw us a word picture so we know exactly what you're working with.

Comment: Is it _possible_? Sure, all things are _possible_... Is it _recommended_? Most likely no. As noted, a picture of the boards showing _how_ (in which direction(s)) they are out of square would be most helpful. You can [edit] that into your question.